# Using stringstream's ignore

Tags: c++, c++98

I am trying to use a `stringstream` as a buffer but I am unable to update the underlying `streambuf` :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 

int main () {
    std::stringstream ss(std::ios_base::app|std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::out); //ostringstream gives the same output
    ss << "foo";
    std::cout << "position get: " << ss.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "position put: " << ss.tellp() << std::endl;
    ss << "b";
    std::cout << "position get: " << ss.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "position put: " << ss.tellp() << std::endl;
    char c;
    ss >> c;
    std::cout << "position get: " << ss.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "position put: " << ss.tellp() << std::endl;
    ss.ignore(1);
    std::cout << "position get: " << ss.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "position put: " << ss.tellp() << std::endl;

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
position get: 0
position put: 3
position get: 0
position put: 4
position get: 1
position put: 4
position get: 2
position put: 4
foob
```

Is it possible to force a reallocation of the `streambuf` underlying object ? If not, is this reallocation automatic and in which circumstance is it triggered ?

I know I can use `ss.str` to change the underlying buffer. But it is a pain to use it to manually update the buffer to a `substr`'s version.

Note: I am doing a school project and must compile to c++98, hence, if you have a solution which is comptabible, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by triggering the reallocation of the internal storage?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am using this `stream` in many places of a common codebase of a web server. I was hoping to making it "increase" by using `operator<<` and "decrease" by using `operator>>` (or `ignore`). I was hoping that I could at least control the size of the buffer so that it does not explode (each socket has such a stream).

Comment: This is really not what stringstream is for. It's for simple, specific use cases. For highly specialized situations, like what you describe, one always need to implement their own, tailored algorithms.

Comment: Reading a char from the stream, or `ignore()`'ing it, doesn't discard the character. The stream still has to support `ss.unget()` to make the character appear again.

Comment: I understand, but ignoring multiple characters does not seem to do the trick either.